# JavaFX. Как заполнить поля при запуске приложения?

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте! Совсем недавно начал изучать Java и в частности GUI на JavaFX2.
Есть приложение, которое при запуске считывает файлы в корневой (для приложения) директории и показывает окно с полями. Проблема в том, как автоматизировать заполнение полей.

```
//Main.java
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    /* Получаем директорию, в которой запущено приложение */
    public static String mDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui/winMain.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("winMain");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 443));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Есть так же класс Controller.java, в котором прописан обработчик клика по кнопке

```
//Controller.java
package com;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML public ListView winMainList;
    @FXML public Label winMainDir;
    @FXML public Label winMainCXls;

    public void winMainListUpdate (ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ObjCtrl mWin = new ObjCtrl();
        mWin.mainUpdate(winMainDir, winMainCXls, winMainList);
    }
}
```

Связка Controller + FXML работает замечательно. По нажатию кнопки подгружаются необходимые данные и поля заполняются. Проблема заключается в том, что бы заставить приложение заполнять эти данные при запуске.

Пытался добавлять добавлять метод (условно назовём его "dwld") в Controller содержащий тоже самое, что и winMainListUpdate, а дальше прописывать в Main.java в start

```
Controller ctrl = new Controller();
ctrl.dwld();
```

Но данный способ не срабатывает, вылетает ошибка "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Пробовал варианты запуска заполнения через конструктор Controller, но так же не получилось.

Что я делаю не так? И какие возможны варианты для решения задачи?

Подозреваю, что всё элементарно и хожу вокруг да около правильного решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример:

```
   winMainList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(List<String> something);
```

Вот с учетом новых условий:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
      winMainList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(List<String> something);
   }

}
```

Comment: Это всё прописано в методе mainUpdate объекта ObjCtrl и работает при клике на кнопку. Мне интересно, как можно заполнить данный список и лейблы при запуске приложения

Comment: Ой, проглядел. Тогда еще проще. Контроллеру воткни интерфейс Initializable. И у тебя будет метод выполняемый при запуске интерфейса(там вставь код заполнения.)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Действительно, всё просто

Comment: @Rihard Brugekhaim new List<String> - не получится так у тебя сделать

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov - new List<String> - это образец данных, которые туда вгоняют. Да, у List нет конструктора, но это более информативно, нежели втыкать как пример более конкретную разновидность.

Comment: @RihardBrugekhaim мне кажется, что лучше писать сразу правильно, потому что потом, возможно, это будет читать человек, который не до конца разбирается в Java, и у него не будет компилироваться код.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, Rihard Brugekhaim, за наводку!
Дописал в Controller.java и всё заработало, как нужно.

```
@FXML private void initialize () {
    ObjCtrl mWin = new ObjCtrl();
    mWin.mainUpdate(winMainDir, winMainCXls, winMainList);
}
```